# Making an enum where index 0 returns a blank string

Tags: c#, enums, enumeration

How do I make an enum where if you try to use ToString() on index 0 of the enum, it will return either:

1. a string that contains an invisible character, or
2. an empty string with a length of 0.

Things I have tried:

```cs
public enum PowersOfTen
{
    "" = 0, // identifier expected
    thousand = 1,
    million = 2,
    billion = 3,
    // etc
}
```

```cs
public enum PowersOfTen
{
      = 0, // identifier expected
    thousand = 1,
    million = 2,
    billion = 3,
    // etc
}
```

```cs
public enum PowersOfTen
{
    /**/ = 0, // identifier expected
    thousand = 1,
    million = 2,
    billion = 3,
    // etc
}
```

Thanks in advance!

[EDIT]
This was meant to be powers of 1000, not 10, my bad!

Comment: You are likely misusing `enums` You can however, use attributes on the Enumeration value. Or an custom extension method

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: Why not just use a Dictionary<int, string>? it seems like it might fit your use case better

Comment: and why is `PowersOfTen.thousand == 1`? 10^1 = 10 and 10^1000 wont fit in this textfield (kdding) .. Really, the 'why do you want to do this?' question is important.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's possible, and even if it was it's a terrible idea. Enums should be used to help with code readability, not to display to users. BTW, 1000^0 = 1 (like 1^0, 10^0 and 3453465^0 for that matter...)

Comment: @Zohar Peled I know that 1000^0 = 1, I just want to display the power of thousand value (e.g 250 thousand). Obviously, a normal person says "925" and not "925 ones" so I wanted to see if the first value of an enum can be blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# Language Reference defines an enumeration type as

> [a value type defined by a set of **named** constants of the
> underlying integral numeric type.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

So every value in your enum declaration must have a name, which implies that an empty string is not valid in that context.
As several commenters hinted, if you need the empty string as a value, then using an enum is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public enum PowersOfTen
{
    [Display(Name = "")]
    None = 0,
    thousand = 1,
    million = 2,
    billion = 3,
    // etc
}
```

Then when you call it, just use the method     GetDisplayName(); and it should work.